# Can't run non-native games [wine-ge, nvidia proprietary]

Tags: nvidia, wine

I'm on manjaro linux and using [wine-ge-custom](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/wine-ge-custom) package. Somewhere around 8.x releases both wine and proton stopped running any games. Lutris log says this:

```
wine: Using setpriority to control niceness in the [-11,11] range
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  156 (NV-GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  43 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  424
  Current serial number in output stream:  425
Monitored process exited.
```

I tried selecting and running older lutris-GE-Proton7-43 in lutris interface, and it works fine, but choosing the lutris-GE-Proton8-5 in the same GUI results in error, the same as above.

Changing dxvk/vkd3d/etc to other version doesn't help. Reinstalling `nvidia-dkms`/`mesa` packages doesn't help either.

This behavior occurs only with wine8+ on Nvidia. When I force to use integrated AMD, games are starting fine. Native games, run with `prime-run` are also works fine.

I found out a guy with the same problem, but there's no solution to it in this thread: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=269259

Also, it's not unexpected, but just in case: under wayland session everything works fine too

Answer (score 0):

My only solution was to boot in only nvidia mode or run with wine/proton 7 and start the game then.

It seems somehow the prime-run is broken with proton/wine 8+ at the moment.

A way to switch(log out and log in) between modes is https://github.com/Askannz/optimus-manager